# Oracle SQL - Problem displaying using the foreign key

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to display all of the products showing the dates they have been sold but also all of the products that haven't been sold either.

I have two tables: `Products` and `Sales`.  The column names are:

### Products

- prod_id
- prod_name

#### Sales

- prod_id
- date_of_sale

The two tables are linked using the `prod_id` column but I just cant seem to get the products that have not been sold to display as well as the ones with sales.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.prod_id, p.product_name, s.date_of_sale
FROM  products p
   ,  sales    s
WHERE s.prod_id(+) = p.prod_id  
;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use a left outer join between Products and Sales:

```
SELECT p.PROD_ID, p.PRODUCT_NAME, s.DATE_OF_SALE
  FROM PRODUCTS p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT PROD_ID, DATE_OF_SALE
                     FROM SALES) s
    ON (s.PROD_ID = p.PROD_ID)
```

Can't play with it at the moment but I think that should get what you want.  You should get all PROD_ID's and PRODUCT_NAME's from PRODUCTS, and all DATE_OF_SALE from SALES.  If there are no DATE_OF_SALE for a product, you should still see the product.

Share and enjoy.